# How to import large json file into mysql using table data table import wizard?

Tags: json, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to upload the Yelp dataset found here https://www.yelp.com/dataset into mysql workbench in order to analyze the dataset using SQL. The dataset has 5 JSON files. When I first try to import the file I get this message:

"This file appears to be a JSON filetype, and the size is over 100MB, which will take a long time to import. If possible, obtain the data in CSV format instead. Do you wish to continue with this file anyway?"

After pressing continue, I get this message:

"Can't analyze file. Please try to change encoding type. If that doesn't help, maybe the file is not: json, or the file is empty."

I've tried to format the JSON file in Sublime Text by using the "Pretty JSON" package, but I get this message:

"Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 150347 column 1 (char 434 - 118861583)"

If anyone has experience with this dataset or is able to explain the errors/give me a solution I would really appreciate it.

Comment: How is the JSON formatted? and how is the table formatted? Can you provide schemas?

Comment: @arcee123 Here is the documentation provided by yelp https://www.yelp.com/dataset/documentation/main

Comment: what do you want your table to look like?

Comment: It sounds like you're running into issues trying to import a large JSON file into MySQL Workbench. 1st solution can be to convert the JSON file to a CSV format, which is more compatible with MySQL and can be imported more quickly. You can use a tool such as "json2csv" to convert the JSON file to a CSV file.  Another solution is to try to import the data in chunks. You can use a tool such as jq to extract smaller chunks of data from the JSON file, and then import those chunks into MySQL. This way you can avoid running into memory issues or timeouts while trying to import the entire file at once